# Can I sniff UDPlite traffic in scapy

Tags: scapy, sniffing

I want to sniff UDP Lite traffic using sniff() function in scapy, but udplite is not supported by scapy so we can't execute :`sniff(filter="udplite")`
So I want to write a filter in scapy to specify that the protocol is IP and the field "proto" in IP Header is 136 (which matches UDP Lite).

Is such filter possible in scapy, and in this case, how can I write it? Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who may have the same problem, I have found the answer

```
sniff(filter="ip and proto 136")
```